# How to parse boolean into NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, boolean

I have following method that does some stringbuilding, but unfortunately i am having problem with parsing the boolean to my NSString.

The code is following:

```
- (void)setToolOutput:(int) outputNumber state: (BOOL) value {
    NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this=%i is=%c",outputNumber,value];
    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [OutputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

I have tried to parse it by using `%c` for char, and `%s` as string of chars. Both ways outputs my boolean as a `question mark turned upside down`.

EDIT: I want it to parse as `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Boolean is basically an integer, so you can use `%i` to get its decimal representation.
What you usually want is this:

`NSString *booleanString = (value) ? @"True" : @"False";`

Comment: I think this is one of the very few cases where the ternary expression is stylistically preferable

Comment: @joerick that's a very broad statement, there are plenty of times when a ternary operator will clean things up without losing readability

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Sorry for my mistake

You can also check boolean value to throw your prefer string like "True" or "False"

```
        NSString *target = @"";
        if(tmp)
        {
            target = @"True";
        }
        else {
            target = @"False";
        }

        // use target variable as you prefer
```

Comment: I have tried this already, i get an exception according to @Paul.s